# comparable math symbols in brackets of python array

Tags: python, arrays

Suppose I have the array:

```py
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

And I run this:

```py
print(array[0<=3])
```

What is this called? How does it work?

Comment: `0<=3` is just doing a boolean operation. So you are doing `array[True]`. Python sees `True` as `1`, so at the end it is just `array[1]`, which returns `2`

Comment: This is probably some question from a programming course, trying to teach something about types in Python, or some really misguided code assuming the language works in a way that it doesn't. It works, but probably not as you expect. Also, calling a `list` in Python `array` doesn't change the fact that it's a `list` and not an `array.array` nor a `numpy.ndarray`, which are the common types of arrays you'll encounter, other than lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0<=3` is `True`, which is understood as `1`, so `array[True]` is `array[1]`

Besides, `array[False]` is `array[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't anything but a simple indexing.

An expression of inequality returns a boolean value. Either `True` (`value=1`) or `False` (`value=0`). Inserting it inside the brackets `[` and `]` means that you are evaluating the inequality and using the result for an index search.

For example, you have:

```py
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
print(arr[100 < 4]) #Which is False
```

It will print:

```
1 # Which is equivalent to arr[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

your code output : 2

```
print(array[5<2])
```

**= false = 0 (array[0] == 1)**

```
print(array[1<2])
```

**= true = 1 (array[1] == 2)**

If you set array to [5,7],
The output will change to false = 5, true = 7.

This is because 0 means false, 1 means true.

This results in these outputs to refer to [0]th and [1]th values respectively in of array.

Comment: Can you please make your explanation after each code block more clear?